# Earlier in time vs. later in time

Tags: time

I'm currently a bit confused about the meaning of "earlier in time" and "later in time". Let's say that the current time point is x and let us define t1 = x - 5s and t2 = x - 10s.

Which one is earlier in time and which one is later in time?

Comment: Are you asking "Is t1 earlier or later in time than t2?" or something else?

Comment: _Earlier_ and _later_ are comparatives. That means there has to be a _than_ clause stating the baseline for comparison. No _than_ clause, no baseline. No baseline, no equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is relative.

t1 is later in time (relative to t2), but earlier in time (relative to x).

In order for something to be "later" or "earlier", there has to be a reference point.